# SQL Server: Login failed (for win user, instead the specified one)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005

While connecting to a remote SQL Server 2005 from my C# code I get a login error (`Login failed for user X`) This 'user X' appears to be the windows user, instead of the one I specified in my connection string, that was a SQL Server user.

Anyone knows the problem here? The server is in another machine, and I cannot make changes on it, but I can check its configuration.

The connection string:

```
server=XXX; database=XXX; user id=XXX; password=XXX; Trusted_Connection=yes; 
connection timeout=30
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

`Trusted_Connection=yes;` has the effect of using the Windows user instead of the credentials specified in the connection string. Try removing `Trusted_Connection` and it should work better.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly the problem.